# How to combine SystemJs relative path and test using karma/jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, systemjs

I am currently using systemJs relative path in my component with this syntax in my .ts files:

```
declare var __moduleName:string;

@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  ...
})
...
```

All works fine untill I want to import this component in a test. I got this following non-verbose error from karma :

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
{
  "originalErr": {}
}
```

If I erase the line :

```
moduleId: __moduleName,
```

from the component transcrypted .js file, all my test works well.

If someone has an idea how to combine this systemjs relative-paths syntax and karma / jasmine tools, it would be welcome.

Comment: Do you get an error when doing tsc with __moduleName?

Comment: I have the followings error on all my import statement : 
error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
But this is not related to the __moduleName syntax I think...

Comment: What if you use `module.id` and just `declare var module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Angular2's best practice is to use `commonjs` for your `moduleId` entry and compile your app using `commonjs`.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Using `commonjs` compilation will work fine with karma/jasmine and with angular2 aswell.

You'll simply have to replace

```
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  ...
})
...
```

with

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  ...
})
...
```

and remove

```
declare var __moduleName:string;
```

Comment: Replacing "module": "system" by "module": "commonjs" in my tsconfig.json break the entire application, I get the following :
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: You should delete every .js files coming from your .ts files and run tsc again.

Comment: I had to rewrite few things in my systemjs config file to make it works! Now all is fine, thanks for your help @Supamiu